# Is it possible to read the version of a Google App Engine app at runtime?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have the version number set in my app.yaml to something like 'rc1'.  I'd like to be able to read the current version for a status/health check URL.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, take a look at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Environment there is a `CURRENT_VERSION_ID` variable that should tell you that.